# Using Eclipse Indigo for JSF 2.0 project

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jstl, eclipse-indigo

I plan to do a JSF 2.0 project in Eclipse Indigo. But, in HelloWorld project, I'm facing a problem. I've included all the required libraries but the server is not identifying some of the classes of jstl. For further information, have a look at the following snapshot, and please respond soon, if anybody knows the solution[image].

Answer (score 0):

Try with the a newer version of mojarra.. (you are using 2.0.0) grab it from here

[JSF mojarra 2.1.7](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.7/javax.faces-2.1.7.jar)